# Puppeteer window not scrollable

Tags: puppeteer, codeceptjs

I am writing test in CodeceptJS.
My settings is:

```
  exports.config = {
  tests: './*_test.js',
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    Puppeteer: {
      url: '',
      show: true,
      defaultView: null,
      userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
    },
  },
```

But when I run my test, Chromium browser have no vertical scroll. When I load my testing url in not automated browser, page loads correctly with ability to scroll my page. What I am missing in my setup to make browser to work as normal browser when using non headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Chrome setting to config solved my issue:

```
        chrome: {
            args: ['--window-size=1920,1080'],
        },
```